# Python 3 and tkinter, thread join blocks main thread forever

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

So basically I have a class, let's say SerialClass, that creates a local thread to update a combobox, the constructor looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, master):

    ...
    # Local thread.
    self.__thread = threading.Thread(target=self.__thread_handler)
    self.__thread_finished = False
    self.__thread.start()
```

This is the function that the thread executes, it just updates a combobox with values.

```
def __thread_handler(self):
    while not self.__thread_finished:
        # Update the ports continously.
        self.update_ports()
    ...
```

This the function I use to exit the thread:

```
def thread_exit(self):
    self.__thread_finished = True
    self.__thread.join()
```

Another class, let's say App, instantiates the class SerialClass. App creates a Tk object and starts the main application using this method:

```
def run(self):
    # Handle the close window event.
    self.__root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.__on_close)
    # Start the application and wait for user events.
    self.__root.mainloop()
```

This is the on_close method:

```
def __on_close(self):
    # When the application finishes, handle the rest of the threads.
    self.__serialui.thread_exit()
    # Destroy the root window as expected.
    self.__root.destroy()
```

The problem I have is that the program flow never reaches the root.destroy() function, for some reason the main thread is blocked forever when I call thread_exit function. If I comment the self.update_ports() in the thread_handler function, all the processes close gracefully.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related but actually Python is changing all the object names starting with double underscore. So `__thread` is `_SerialClass__thread`. To indicate "private" objects use *one* underscore.

Comment: yeah I know that, the use of two underscores is intended. I dont think it is related but I might be wrong

Comment: tkinter isn't thread safe. You can't reliably update widgets from a thread other than the one they were created in.

Comment: One way you could perform what you are trying to do is using a class variable (let's say `self.__ports` for this one and make it of type `<list>`). It could work using your thread to update this list and update the contents of your combobox inside your main thread.

Comment: I wasn't aware that tkinter was not thread safe, googling this returned a lot of results. Funny thing is that the GUI updates OK without problems, it's only when I finish the application when I find problems. Thank you all for your help.